# Can I force an ios7 device to load an app using ios6?

Tags: ios7, xcode4, xcode5, ios6.1

I have an ios6.1 app that will soon be updated to ios7 (there's a bottleneck for resources in marketing right now) but for the time being I need to make this app available on our enterprise account. We're not using the app store so apple standards are irrelevant.  When I download the app on my iPhone 5s it looks terrible.  I've set the deployment target and base sdk to 6.1 but it still doesn't look like it should.  Looks exactly right on my old iphone 4 (running 6.1) that I'm testing it on, but my 5s still insists on using 7.1 which jumbles up the app something fierce.  I've seen this work before, any thoughts?  Thank you!